# Visual Studio 2019 WinUI 3 Duplicate entry error

Tags: visual-studio, winui-3

```
Error PRI175: 0x80073b0f - Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate entry. MyApplication (Package) C:\MyApplication (Package)\GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE
```

<- This is the error I always get if I want to compile my .NET 5 WinUI 3 (0.8.1) Desktop Packaged Project.
Either on the Packaging Project or on the main Application Project.

And bevor this error ther is **always** this error:

```
Error PRI222: 0x80073b0f - Unspecified error occurred.  MyApplication (Package) C:\MyApplication (Package)\GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE
```

On the internet, I couldn't find any solution.

Can please somebody help?

*Some additional info:*

- I have the latest version of Visual Studio Community (16.10.3)
- I also have the latest version of my Project Reunion/Windows App SDK NuGet packages (0.8.1)
- ... and each other NuGet is also up to date
- My C# application uses some [DllImport] and [ComImport]
- I also use the PInvoke from Microsoft's CsWin32 project
- I tried to create a new project and copy code file content by file content into new files but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, what I did was to remove all the images from the assets and it worked, then I was adding little by little until I found the assets that gave error.
I understand that the error is generic, VS does not help much.